# Adding encryption to a TCP Stream?

Tags: c++, encryption, tcp, liblacewing

I'm using a TCP Client Server Library called Lacewing.

http://lacewing-project.org/docs/

What I noticed is that messages I send and receive are in plain text. Is there a way to encrypt / decrypt the messages easily given that I use TCP? How could I add something like TLS en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security or similar?

Thanks

The library is pretty high level but here is client server in a nutshell:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>  
#define  LacewingFunction
#include "Lacewing.h"

void onReceive (Lacewing::Server &Server, Lacewing::Server::Client &Client,
                char * Data, int Size) {
                    /* callback body */
                    std::cout << Data << "\n";
}

void onConnect (Lacewing::Server &Server, Lacewing::Server::Client &Client)
{
    std::cout << "Connected!" << "\n";
    Client.Send("TestingS");
}



void onReceiveC (Lacewing::Client &Client, char * Data, int Size)
{
    std::cout << Data << "\n";
    Client.Send("TesingC");
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    if(s == "server")
    {
        Lacewing::EventPump pump;
        Lacewing::Server* server = new Lacewing::Server(pump);
        server->onReceive(onReceive);
        server->onConnect(onConnect);
        server->Host(1234);
        pump.StartEventLoop();
    }
    else
    {
        Lacewing::EventPump pump;
        Lacewing::Client* server = new Lacewing::Client(pump);
        server->onReceive(onReceiveC);
        server->Connect("192.168.2.12",1234);
        pump.StartEventLoop();
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You could try using another library that is commonly used called Boost::Asio which is a nice library that has built-in SSL support. If you want to code in C, OpenSSL has a nice library that is simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: yes. Your two basic options are SSL/TLS and IPsec. SSL would be implemented in your application; IPsec would be outside of your control.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238440/77939) to a related question.

You'd have to post some of your networking code if you want help on how to adapt it to SSL/TLS.

---

**Edit**: If you don't want to modify the source code to Lacewing, it seems to me that the easiest solution for you might be to use something like [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) to protect your traffic.

Comment: After you accept the connection, you'd need to do the TLS negotiation, certificate checking, etc, before proceeding to the point where you allow your client/server code to send/receive data. Basically everything stunnel does. ;-) You'd probably want to add a new API to Lacewing; something like `SSLServer`/`SSLClient`; the server would need the ability to specify its certificate.

Comment: Where would be a tutorial that might show how to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Lacewing has something about certificates but Im not sure that's it http://lacewing-project.org/docs/server/CertificateLoaded.html

Comment: Oh, what am I thinking?! Looks like it might have some level of SSL/TLS support already. Try loading a certificate!

Comment: I'm having trouble loading one.

Comment: With OpenSSL, connecting to the server yields result 21, self signed certificate, but, with my client it always says secure handshake failed.

Comment: Maybe there is an API to allow the client to trust the self-signed cert? I guess you need to determine how to configure the chain of trust on the client.