# How to improve security connection on socket

Tags: c++, c, security, sockets

I develop my instant messages server with c/c++ then I want to improve the security by change sockets with some encoding or security communication. Please you advice and guide me.

Best regards
Warradorn S.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate question, you may get more answers here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236526/looking-for-a-high-level-c-ssl-library

Comment: You are looking for TLS, probably via the OpenSSL library.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.openssl.org/
Use it as much as you want in your socket communication